# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading pipe) - Angular Jasmine testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have a service `service1`. I want to test the method `getDetails()` of this. This method uses another service `service2` to make an HTTP call using `getData()` method and returns a promise. The function is as below:

```
service1 {

   constructor(
       private service2 : Service2,
       private service3 : Service3
   ){}
   
   getDetails(id: string): any{
       let url = Utilty.format(id);
       return service2.getData(url).pipe(map(this.service3.setData)).toPromise();
   }
}
```

The code that I have written for testing is as below:

```
describe('service1', () => {
    let service1: Service1;

    let service2Spy: Jasmine.spyObj(Service2);
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports:  [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [HttpClient,
            {provide: Service2, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Service2', ['getData'])}
            ]
        });
        service1: TestBed.get(Service1);
        service2Spy: TestBed.get(Service2);
    })

    it('check if getData returns correct response', function done() {
        // in respnse I have taken a constant json that is expected
        service2Spy.getData.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(of(response)));
        service1.getDetails('abc').then((result)=> {
            expect(service2Spy.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        })

    })
})
```

I want to test whether the below scenarios:

1. Is `getData()` is called or not?
2. What are the parameters with which `getData` is called?
3. Are we getting the correct response from `getDetails`?

But I keep getting this error:

```
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
```

Comment: The absolute minimum requirement for a test double is that it matches the interface of the thing that it's supposed to be replacing. Your code (presumably, although not necessarily, correctly) expects the method to return an observable, and the test double returns a _promise_ of an observable.

Comment: Please use your actual code for this situation because your code have lots of typos that would have been thrown aside from the error you pointed out.